# GUI not adding panels

Tags: java, swing

beginner using GUI and cannot figure out why this is not adding the fields in my GUI. It opens the frame but it is empty. No errors are flagged either. Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Project3 extends JFrame {

    public Project3() {

        //set layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));

        //add radio panel
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();

        //set Radio Buttons
        JRadioButton iter = new JRadioButton("Iteration", true);
        JRadioButton recur = new JRadioButton("Recursion", true);

        //add radio buttons to group
        ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup.add(iter);
        radioGroup.add(recur);
        radioPanel.add(iter);
        radioPanel.add(recur);
        recur.setSelected(true);

        //add another panel
        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 5, 5));

        //add text fields and button
        JLabel enter = new JLabel("Enter n:");
        JTextField eight = new JTextField(8);
        //?????????????????????????????
        JButton compute = new JButton("Compute");
        JLabel result = new JLabel("Result:");
        JTextField eight1 = new JTextField(8);
        JLabel efficiency = new JLabel("Efficiency:");
        JTextField eight2 = new JTextField(8);

        //add items to panel
        secondPanel.add(enter);
        secondPanel.add(eight);
        secondPanel.add(compute);
        secondPanel.add(result);
        secondPanel.add(eight1);
        secondPanel.add(efficiency);
        secondPanel.add(eight2);

        add(radioPanel);
        add(secondPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 3");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a plain `JFrame`. You need to create an instance of the `Project3` class you wrote.

I.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create frame
    Project3 frame = new Project3();
    frame.setTitle("Project 3");
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks James... knew it was an easy oversight. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're `Project3` extends from `JFrame`, but in your `main` method you create an entirely separate instance of `JFrame` and ignore your `Project3` class altogether

This is just adding confusion, instead, extend `Project3` from `JPanel` and the ADD an instance of it to your newly created `JFrame`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Project3 extends JPanel {

    public Project3() {

        //set layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));

        //add radio panel
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();

        //set Radio Buttons
        JRadioButton iter = new JRadioButton("Iteration", true);
        JRadioButton recur = new JRadioButton("Recursion", true);

        //add radio buttons to group
        ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup.add(iter);
        radioGroup.add(recur);
        radioPanel.add(iter);
        radioPanel.add(recur);
        recur.setSelected(true);

        //add another panel
        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 5, 5));

        //add text fields and button
        JLabel enter = new JLabel("Enter n:");
        JTextField eight = new JTextField(8);
        //?????????????????????????????
        JButton compute = new JButton("Compute");
        JLabel result = new JLabel("Result:");
        JTextField eight1 = new JTextField(8);
        JLabel efficiency = new JLabel("Efficiency:");
        JTextField eight2 = new JTextField(8);

        //add items to panel
        secondPanel.add(enter);
        secondPanel.add(eight);
        secondPanel.add(compute);
        secondPanel.add(result);
        secondPanel.add(eight1);
        secondPanel.add(efficiency);
        secondPanel.add(eight2);

        add(radioPanel);
        add(secondPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 3");
                frame.add(new Project3());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

By doing this, you decouple your code and provide a greater level of re-use to your component, now you can add `Project3` to what ever container you like

Answer (score 1):

You never actually create a `Project3` - just a `JFrame`.

Pehaps

```
// Create frame
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 3");
```

Was supposed to be

```
// Create frame
JFrame frame = new Project3();
```